# Self-reference @ManyToOne and @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

I am sending Cart

```
{
"otherId": "12345",
"items": [
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "1",
                "description": "Nested Description",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "1.1",
                        "description": "Nested Description"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "1.2",
                        "description": "Another Nested Description"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "2",
                "description": "Another Nested Description"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Cart {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private String id;

@Column(name = "other_id")
private String otherId;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH}/*, mappedBy="cart"*/)
@JoinColumn(name = "cart_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private List<Item> items;
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Item {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private String id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id",referencedColumnName ="id")
private Item parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Item> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

All objects are saved, but cart_id is added in only one item, and parent_id is not filled in items.
The problem is in the connections between entity, but I do not understand which ones. As far as I understand hibernate should automatically add id in child items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate saves your objects precisely as they are configured.

You have one parent Item that has a link to children, and some of them have links to their children, but none of them have links to their parents.

If you introduced bi-directional dependencies between entities you should build objects with circular links.
For example, this code will produce the expected result in the database if we persist the `Item parent` object.

```
Item parent = new Item();

Item child1 = new Item();
Item child2 = new Item();

List<Item> children = List.of(child1, child2);
parent.setChildren(children);
child1.setParent(parent);
child2.setParent(parent);
```

| id | parent_id | cart_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | 1 | null |
| 3 | 1 | null |

But if we comment out the last two lines in this code snippet - we will have something that could seem unexpected in the database table.

```
Item parent = new Item();

Item child1 = new Item();
Item child2 = new Item();

List<Item> children = List.of(child1, child2);
parent.setChildren(children);
//child1.setParent(parent); - wrong! you should assign circular links manually!
//child2.setParent(parent);
```

The result is `null` values in column `parent_id`. Obviously, the reason is that the `parent` field of these `Item` objects is `null`.

| id | parent_id | cart_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | null | null |
| 3 | null | null |

Because the object that is defined in JSON has only unidirectional links it will be saved as shown in the second code snippet.

You have two options to fight this problem:

1. Ensure that objects with circular bidirectional dependencies have been configured correctly before saving
2. Remove unnecessary bidirectional dependencies from your entity definitions.

I'd prefer the latter. You rarely need bidirectional associations between objects. Moreover - it doesn't suites the concept of an object in Object Oriented Programming. For example, a car consists of an engine and wheels and if we create such an object we will try to reflect real-life relationships in our abstraction: class `Car` will have a link to the `Engine` instance and collection of `Wheel` objects. But if you try to add a link that leads to `Car` to the `Engine` it will be in contradiction with the real-life object that you are trying to describe. The engine doesn't consist of a car, that's why `Engine` shouldn't have a link to its "parent".

The root of the problem with the `cart_id` is the same. If we look at your JSON - your `Cart` consists of only one `Item`, and if we persist such an object to the database - only one item will have the cart_id. You have some kind of hierarchical structure of the order, but you want to save it in a database as a flat object. Hibernate helps to save your objects to the storage, it can't save some other objects only based on your entities' definitions.
From this point of view - the expected behavior - is that only one `Item` should be persisted with `cart_id` because only one `Item` object has a direct link to the `Cart`. The others have this link set to `null`.